# How many sequences of subsets of a set A there are such that the union of all the subsets equals A

Tags: combinatorics

I have been working on exercises in a combinatorics book. I have come to a problem that I am having difficulty solving.

The problem states :

"We are given a natural number n and a finite nonempty set A. Show that there are exactly
$(2^{n} - 1)^{|A|}$ sequences $(A_{1},A_{2},...,A_{n})$, formed by subsets of $A$
s.t. $A = A_{1} \bigcup A_{2} \bigcup \dots \bigcup A_{n}$."

A hint from the book says that for each $x \in A$ there are $2^{n}-1$ ways of choosing the subsets $A_{i}$ which contain $x$. This is supposed to be key to the solution.

I am somewhat confused by this problem (and its hint) and have not been able to solve it. Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: The idea is this:  for each $x\in A$ you must choose which of the slots to put it in.  You can put it is as many slots as you like, so long as it goes in at least one.   That is true for every element in $A$ and the choice for one element has nothing to do with the choice(s) for any other.

Comment: You don't need to tell us it's a combinatorics problem in the title. That's one thing the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for a finite set $A$ you can give the elements an order say $A=\{a_1,\cdots ,a_{|A|} \}$. Let $(A_1,A_2,\cdots ,A_n)$ be one of the sequences you are interested, then for every element $x\in A$ there has to be some indices(call them $b_1,\cdots b_{ 
 k_x}$) such that $x\in A_{b_i}$ for all those indices. So notice that you can represent this as a string of $1's$ and $0's$ you put a $1$ in the position $i$ iff $x\in A_i$ But you can do this with every element $x\in A$ so you are creating $|A|$ of such sequences. Notice that this binary strings are all of them except the one in which of all the elements are $0's$(because then that element is not going to be in the union).

Answer (score 0):

For each $x\in A$ let $I_x=\{k\in[n]:x\in A_k\}$. Since $\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k=A$, we know that $I_x\ne\varnothing$ for each $x\in A$. Thus, there are $2^n-1$ possibilities for each $I_x$, and there are $(2^n-1)^{|A|}$ possible assignments of non-empty subsets of $[n]$ to the $|A|$ elements of $A$. Each of those assignments uniquely specifies an $n$-tuple $\langle A_n,\ldots,A_n\rangle$ of subsets of $A$ whose union is $A$: $A_k=\{x\in A:k\in I_x\}$. And each possible $n$-tuple of subsets of $A$ whose union is $A$ is specified in this way.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence $(A_1, \dots, A_n)$ s.th. $A = A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n$ allows me to define a function $I_{A_1, \dots, A_n} : A \rightarrow M$ where $M$ is the set $\{0, 1\}^n \setminus (0, \dots, 0)$ with $2^n - 1$ elements.

$I_{A_1, \dots, A_n}(x) := (1 \text{ if } x \in A_1 \text{ otherwise }0, \dots, 1 \text{ if } x \in A_n \text{ otherwise }0)$.

This function never returns $(0, 0, \dots, 0)$, because then $x$ would not be in $A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n$.

Similar, for every function $I : A \rightarrow M$ we can define $A_i^I := \{ x \vert I(x)_i = 1\}$ and check that we get $A = A_1^I \cup \dots \cup A_n^I$.

This defines an isomorphism between the set of all your sequences and the space of all functions from $A$ to $M$. This means they have the same amount of elements - $(2^n-1)^{|A|}$.